# Magento2 Billing address issue for paypal

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, paypal-express, billing-address

When I registered new customer and place order via **paypal** for **virtual** and **downloadable** product It will not ask me for **billing** and **shipping** address.

But will display billing address in `{{var telephone}}` style in customer account and in admin, and blank in email.